# How to return MYSQL PROCEDURE errors

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure, mysql-5.5

I have a large MySQL procedure with a transactional commit, called from PHP with some loops: blocks of max. 50 entries and I have 24213 total entries.

One of these loops is generating some problems but I can't get the returned error. I have tried with a HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, with SHOW ERRORS and  RESIGNAL, but I didn't get anything about this error.

Every execution is registering this results in a table as a log and I want to register that error in it.

EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION:

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE `Procedure01`(
  IN _Ini INT,
  IN _End INT,
  IN _CalcDate DATE
  )
  BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
      BEGIN

        RESIGNAL;
        SHOW ERRORS;

        ROLLBACK;

        SET @sql = CONCAT("INSERT INTO `Log_Procedure` (`From`,`To`,`Datetime`,`Comment`) VALUES ( '", _Ini, "','", _End, "',NOW(),'ERROR: SQLException');");
        PREPARE s FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE s;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

    END;
...
```

I got nothing from this SHOW ERRORS, called from PHP or with a direct CALL from phpMyAdmin.

Another option that could be great it is to get a return from a this kind of execution:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT("INSERT INTO `Log_Procedure` (`From`,`To`,`Datetime`,`Comment`) VALUES ( '", _Ini, "','", _End, "',NOW(),'ERROR: SQLException');");
    PREPARE s FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE s;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Using the out parameter in the parameter list of the stored procedure, you can return the error message

```
@ErrorMessage varchar OUTPUT
```